# How to check if other app has permission of createScreenCaptureIntent

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I want to check if installed app has ability to record my screen for this i'm using this code to get all apps and their permissions but AFAIK there is no permission required to be declared in the manifest file, So how can i detect if app has Permission of createScreenCaptureIntent ?

Here is my code which i'm using right now

```
StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();
PackageManager pm = PackageManager;
var packages = pm.GetInstalledApplications(PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);

foreach (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo in packages)
{
   Log.Debug("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.Name + " Package: applicationInfo.PackageName");
   try
     {
       PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.GetPackageInfo(applicationInfo.PackageName, PackageInfoFlags.Permissions);
       appNameAndPermissions.Append(packageInfo.PackageName + "*******:\n");

       if(packageInfo.Services?.Any(x => x.ForegroundServiceType == ForegroundService.TypeMediaProjection) ?? default) 
       Util.SetRecorderApp(packageInfo.PackageName);

       //Get Permissions
       var requestedPermissions = packageInfo.RequestedPermissions;
       if (requestedPermissions != null &&
           requestedPermissions.Any(x => x == Manifest.Permission.CaptureVideoOutput || x == Manifest.Permission.CaptureSecureVideoOutput || x == Manifest.Permission.SystemAlertWindow))
                    Util.SetRecorderApp(packageInfo.PackageName);
       } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                    System.Console.WriteLine("NameNotFoundException: " + e.Message);
      }
```

Comment: You could try to use `android.media.projection` APIs to do the screen capturing and screen sharing capabilities to your app. https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-5.0.html#ScreenCapture

Comment: My question is how can i check in installed app and identify if app uses **android.media.projection** Permission?

Comment: It requests the Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission. Check the link with the request for the runtime permission. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/permissions?tabs=windows

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT many other apps that don't do video recording also use **Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW** how to differentiate?

Comment: I am not sure whay do you want to differentiate. You could add it in your manifest.  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT I want to filter out the app that has the permission *createScreenCaptureIntent*, yes these apps also uses **android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"** but many other apps that do not record the screen also uses the same permission. I want to filter out only recorders.

Comment: You could check the permission in your own app. But if you need to check the other apps,  you need ask for the developers of these apps.